# Hive SQL cartesian product error.. false positive?

Tags: hive, dbeaver

Frustratingly I keep getting the following error when trying to run my Hive sql query. Removing the where clause seems to resolve the error somehow. I don't see how this could possibly be a cartesian join..

[Hive SQL error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vDXZ.png)

Query:

```
`CREATE TABLE userdb_x.users AS

 

 SELECT

 DISTINCT a.individual_id

 FROM simple.customer a

 LEFT JOIN salesforce.contact b

 ON a.individual_id = b.wcds_individual_id__c

 LEFT JOIN user_dimensions.country_detail d

 ON a.country_code = d.country_code

 LEFT JOIN salesforce.account e

 ON a.company_id = e.wcds_company_id__c

 LEFT JOIN salesforce.users x

 ON b.ownerid = x.id

 LEFT JOIN userdb_x.email_opt_status f

 ON lower(b.email) = lower(f.email)

 WHERE b.ownerid = '12345'`
```

I've tried removing different joins, etc. It seems removing the salesforce.users join or removing the where clause resolves the error.. confusing.